# Regex find a line in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have words like this in a file.

```
"abc
"defgh
"ijklmno
"1234
"123
```

I am able to find the words by using this regexp **^\".*$**
I need to append another quote to the text so that the text becomes a quoted text.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can usually just replace

```
(?<=^").*
```

by

```
$0"
```

Comment: The use of a lookbehind is redundant here.

Comment: Lest I want to include the opening quote in the replacement part, yes. I tend to rather use lookaround than to replace more than necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If your words always start at the beginning of the line you could record a macro and run it from the beginning to the end of the file.

Otherwise you can use regular expressions:
In notepad++ v6.3.3 this worked for me:
Ctrl + F -> Replace -> Regular expression

**Find:** `^\".*$`

**Replace:** `$0"`